# How Can I add degree when the class "zero" is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
$("div.box").click(function () {

    if (this.class != "zero") {
      $("div").removeClass("zero"),
        $(this).addClass("zero")
    }
    var deg = 15 + "deg";
    $(".zero").css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)').nextAll().css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + ')');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just change this to make degree increase in every time you click it.

```
var deg = 15 ;
$(".zero").css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)').nextAll().css('transform', 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
deg++;
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to add every rotate 15degree. For exampl (rotate45+15),(30+15)

Comment: you can make it by doing this

deg +=15; @ Khalig heydarov